# ROS orocos tutorial

Tags: ros, orocos

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am currently reviewing Orocos and would like to use it as my control framework. I would like to use ROS as my transport layer so I have found [rtt_ros_integration](https://github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration) to be *to the point*.

I have read all the orocos doc I could find, and would like to pratise on the [examples](https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/rtt_examples), so I have now installed *rtt-ros-integration* in indigo (under ubuntu 14.04). But it seems that the [orocos component manual](http://www.orocos.org/stable/documentation/rtt/v2.x/doc-xml/orocos-components-manual.pdf) is no longer up-to-date as it states to use the following command line in order to create an orocos component package `rosrun ocl orocreate-pkg HelloWorld`. But this command line outputs an error saying `orocreate-pkg` does not exist in package **ocl**, which is true (I have checked in the said package). The same happens when trying to start the deployer with `rosrun ocl deployer-gnulinux`.

I guess the instructions of the *orocos component manual* correspond to an old version of the ROS / orocos integration. Hence my question: anyone knows more than I do on the new ways to start **orocreate-pkg**, the **deployer**, or the **task browser** with *rtt-ros-integration*?

I have run the [rtt_ros_examples](https://github.com/jhu-lcsr/rtt_ros_examples) (the ops version, not the LUA version which looks bugged), but I could not figure out the answer so far...

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216000/ros-orocos-tutorial/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2015-08-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ok, I think I have some elements for the answer.

Basically:

- Do not follow the steps given in the orocos doc, they are deprecated and should be updated (as for the integration into ROS - the other parts of the doc are still relevant)

  -> the last doc corresponds to version 2.6 of orocos and we are now at version 2.8
- Follow the steps given in the [rtt_ros_integration doc](https://github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration)

In addition to this:

- create a folder in your workspace (as if you were doing a normal ROS package) and put all your code in there (CMakeLists.txt, package.xml, HelloWorld.cpp, helloworld.ops...)
- for the content of these files (CMakeLists.txt, package.xml, HelloWorld.cpp, helloworld.ops...), you can get inspiration from the examples in [rtt_ros_integration_examples](https://github.com/jhu-lcsr/rtt_ros_examples)
- all instructions in helloworld.ops should end with a ";", no idea why...
- no longer use `OCL_CREATE_COMPONENT` in your .cpp, but `ORO_CREATE_COMPONENT`

  -> this is the new way of doing things
- compile your component the normal ROS way (catkin_make in your workspace)
- dynamically load your component: `rosrun rtt_ros deployer -s helloworld.ops -linfo`

Cheers,

Antoine.

---

Originally posted by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) with karma: 955 on 2015-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Balaji](https://answers.ros.org/users/26502/balaji/) on 2016-05-09**:
When i run this code,      rosrun rtt_ros deployer -s helloworld.ops -linfo

I am getting this error,     `/home/coe/ws/underlay/src/rtt_ros_integration/rtt_ros/scripts/deployer: line 5: deployer: command not found`

**Comment by [Balaji](https://answers.ros.org/users/26502/balaji/) on 2016-05-09**:
I cannot see the Helloworld.ops and helloworld.cpp file. I am getting error as `failed to open ocl` when i run catkin_make_isolated --install
and im getting error as `cmake failed`   when i run catkin_make